# Nougat upgrade damaged my notifications?

Tags: notifications, nexus-5x, 7.0-nougat

I updated my Nexus 5X to Nougat and ever since regret the decision.
Previously if I had a notification the illumination light would start working. If I just turned on the display, not unlock, the light would turn off. But now with the update the light just won't stop until I open the app! Overall the notifications interface is pretty bad but this problem is irking me.
How do I make the notification light stop if I press the power button without having to unlock and open the app?